# How to capture user input from a running process?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm running a script portion of which is below:

```
gpg -c --cipher-algo AES256 key
File `key.gpg' exists. Overwrite? (y/N) n
Enter new filename: filekey
```

How can I capture user's input (i.e. "filekey") from a gpg process so that I can assign it to a variable inside the script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `gpg` you can check if the file exists and according read a new file name into a variable and then call `gpg`.

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=${1:-key}     # use argument as filename or `key` by default
filename="${infile}.gpg"

while [ -f "$filename" ] 
do
   echo -n "File $filename exists. Overwrite? (y/N)"
   read option
   case "$option" in
     y|Y )
       rm $filename
       ;;
     * )
       echo -n "Enter new filename:"
       read filename
       ;;
   esac
done

gpg -c --cipher-algo AES256 -o $filename $infile
```

This way `gpg` never gets to ask the question when the file exists.

Comment: Hem, if file exist, gpg will still ask question as there is no `overwrite` flag. More: $filename **have** to exist, it's `$filename.gpg` who have to be created... You have to `filename="key.gpg"`, `rm $filename` before `gpg -c --cipher-algo AES256 -o $filename key`

Comment: Though it's not necessary to have give output file name with `-o` because the gpg will create a bew file `key.jpg` if `key` is given. But I agree the change you did will simulate the `overwrite` effect.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  It definitely answers the problem. But I was kind of thinking "is there a way to tap into the process" so I could access user input.

Comment: @Allfo I dont think that's possible. You can make the process read from a pipe or something and get the name from the pipe. But that's also similar to this. This is probably the cleaner way to achieve in a simple way.